# Thread safe global variable in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to understand the thread safety mechanism in java and I need some help. I have a class:

```
public class ThreadSafe {

    private Executor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

    private long value = 0;

    public void method() {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            this.value++;
        }
    }

    private synchronized long getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ThreadSafe threadSafe = new ThreadSafe();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            threadSafe.executor.execute(new MyThread());
        }

    }

    private static class MyThread extends Thread {

        private ThreadSafe threadSafe = new ThreadSafe();

        private AtomicBoolean shutdownInitialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!shutdownInitialized.get()) {
                threadSafe.method();
                System.out.println(threadSafe.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here I am trying to make the `value` thread safe, to be accessed only by one thread at a time. When I am running this program I see that there is more than one thread operating on the `value` even if I wrap it within the `synchronized` block. Of course this loop will be infinite but its just an example, I am stopping this program manually after few seconds, so I have:

```
2470
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main]
2470
Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main]
2470
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]
```

Different threads are accessing and changing this `value`. Can somebody explain to me why is this so? And how to make this global variable thread safe?

Comment: Wasn't your intention to make long static in this example? Because in any other case there is no threadsafety issue.

Comment: Make sure you notice my answer.  Your `MyThread` class should _not_ extend `Thread` and _should_ implement `Runnable`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each thread has its own `ThreadSafe`, and each `ThreadSafe` has its own, different `value`. Moreover, `synchronized` methods lock on `this`, so each `ThreadSafe` is locking on itself -- and none of them are being shared among threads. This is called thread-locality, and it's the easiest way to ensure thread safety. :)

To get at the experiment that I think you want, you'd need to change `MyThread` such that its constructor takes a `ThreadSafe` argument (instead of constructing one). Then, have the main method create one `ThreadSafe` and give it to each `MyThread` at construction time.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the same value every time because each of your `Runnable`s has its own instance of the `ThreadSafe` class.

If you want them all to share the same class, then you are going to need to only have one instance of `ThreadSafe` and pass it into all of your jobs -- see below.  As mentioned, an `AtomicLong` is the way to go if you want a thread-safe shared `long`.

Also, your `MyThread` class should *not* `extend Thread`.  It should instead `implements Runnable`.  Your code is working because `Thread` already `implements Runnable`.  If you did `myThread.interrupt()` it would not actually be interrupting the thread because it is the thread-pool threads that are calling your `run()` method.

Something like the following would work:

```
ThreadSafe threadSafe = new ThreadSafe();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threadSafe.executor.execute(new MyRunnable(threadSafe));
}
...
private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final ThreadSafe threadSafe;
    public MyRunnable(ThreadSafe threadSafe) {
       this.threadSafe = threadSafe;
    }
    ...
```